# How to get a paragraph text in php

Tags: php, html

I want to get a paragraph data from HTML file into the php code.
In my html file I have the following line:

```
<p style="display: inline;" id="symptoms" name = "symptoms"</p>
```

In the html file `document.getElementById('symptoms').value` gathers all the necessary data I want to use in the php code. 
Obviously, `$symptoms = $_POST['symptoms'];` doesn't get anything. 
How can I get it work?

Comment: You mention you want to retrieve the data "from [an] HTML file" - have you tried reading the file itself into a variable and parsing it with an XML/(X)HTML parser a la [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)?

Comment: I think I was not precise. I have a form which generates some results with JavaScript. “symptoms” is one of the results which is shown to the user at the end. I want to write this “symptom s”to a log file using php.

Comment: How do you send the data? via ajax?

Comment: In the same vein as I think @BurhanKashour is going - why not just grab the data that goes in that `p` from the same datasource your server uses to pass it back to the user? Much easier and less computationally expensive than painting an entire DOM and sending the entire HTML result *back* to the server just to parse a single element's contents.

Answer (score 0):

We can actually get the value inside the symptoms as shown here for Jquery. To use this value as php POST value. We can improvise this by next set of code.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<p style="display: inline;" id="symptoms" name = "symptoms"> HEllo Hari</p>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#symptoms").html());
});
</script>
```

Maybe we modify following code as required to achieve what you expect

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<p style="display: inline;" id="symptoms" name = "symptoms"> HEllo Hari</p>

<form method="POST" action="/*toPHPfilePath*/" id="target" >
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_symptoms" name="symptoms">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#hidden_symptoms").val($("#symptoms").html());
    
    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```